# Building Marcus Savings Calculator in Excel

Tags: calculation, compound-interest, spreadsheet

I'm trying to do some analysis in Google Sheets which involves putting money in [Marcus' High Yield savings account](https://www.marcus.com/us/en/savings/high-yield-savings). For some reason, I can't seem to get my numbers to match the values from their [savings calculator](https://www.marcus.com/us/en/financial-calculators/high-yield-savings-calculator).

I'm using the value of interest rate to be 2.25%, *compounded daily* as mentioned [here](https://www.marcus.com/us/en/resources/build-your-savings/what-is-the-difference-between-apy-and-interest), and the principal being `$10000`, with `$100` being deposited every month for a total period of 2 years.

As per their calculator, this results in an interest of `$507`, whereas with the below formula, I'm getting `$12949` or `$549` as the interest using the formula below.

```
FV(2.25%/365, 365 * 2, -100/30, -10000, 0) - 10000 - 2400
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2.25% is an [annual effective rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation) (same as APY)

```
e = 0.0225
```

Converting the annual effective rate to a monthly rate

```
r = (1 + e)^(1/12) - 1 = 0.00185594
```

Compounding the principal, with `n = 24`

```
10000 (1 + r)^n = 10460.2625
```

Compounding the payments, with `d = 100` and payment at month-end.

```
fv = (d ((1 + r)^n - 1))/r = 2451.9379
```

Adding together

```
2451.9379 + 10460.2625 = 12907
```

In Excel

```
=FV(r, n, -d, -10000)

=FV(0.00185594, 24, -100, -10000)
```

> £12,906.99

```
interest = 12907 - 10000 - 2400 = 507
```

Comment: @Prakhar You’re welcome.